# "/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" while upgrading grub package

Tags: grub2, apt, dpkg

I am facing a problem while installing any program. I get an error of `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. Following is log of the output of `apt-get -f install`. Any idea what's wrong with my package manager?

```
tahir@tahir-Inspiron-1564:/var/www$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for tahir: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic (2.6.35-27.48) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-27-generic                                                                                                 
 *       bcmwl (5.60.48.36+bdcom)...                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic (2.6.35-28.50) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-28-generic                                                                                                 
 *       bcmwl (5.60.48.36+bdcom)...                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic (2.6.35-30.59) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-30-generic                                                                                                 
 *       bcmwl (5.60.48.36+bdcom)...                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 2.6.35.30.38); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--confNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
igure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic
 linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic
 linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**

- Update:

**
Following is the output of `sudo update-grub`

```
tahir@tahir-Inspiron-1564:~$ sudo update-g
update-gconf-defaults  update-grub2           
update-grub            update-gsfontmap       
tahir@tahir-Inspiron-1564:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: 20_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 8: The: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 9: administrator.: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 10: 01_otheros,: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 11: the: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 11: and: not found
```

File /etc/grub.d/README is as given bellow. Don't know why a README should matter. :-/

```
All executable files in this directory are processed in shell expansion order.

  00_*: Reserved for 00_header.
  10_*: Native boot entries.
  20_*: Third party apps.

The number namespace in-between is configurable by system installer and/or
administrator.  For example, you can add an entry to boot another OS as
01_otheros, 11_otheros, etc, depending on the position you want it to occupy in
the menu; and then adjust the default setting via /etc/default/grub.
```

File: /etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

File: /usr/share/grub/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: You should probably start with this `dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`

Comment: Can this error be arising because I have too many kernel images in /boot? I can't find the 'dependency' problem mentioned in the log above as: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: Yes looked for the dependency problem but this log does not help to track the exact dependency issue e.g. it would have been good to have the name of the package for which the dependency issue is popping up or it would have been great to know what that dependency issue is. Still figuring out this. Thanks.

Comment: does my answer sound right?

Comment: readme wouldn't matter. I am on a windows machine right now, I wouldn't be able to help you as much if I was on an Ubuntu machine.  Post your `/etc/default/grub` and your `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`

Comment: would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1447/discussion-between-tmb-and-baltusaj)

Comment: I would have loved that but I need atlease 20 reputation to enable chat. :) I have posted the files you asked for though. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have somehow given the **README** file execution rights, and the `update-grub` script is trying to execute it. Hence the errors.

So remove the execution rights

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/README
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're issue is that you have too many kernel images in /boot.

It looks like you have an error in your grub configuration file. It seems to be breaking here:

```
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
```

Take a look at this question on [linuxmint.com](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=68802&p=397986), it seems to be identical.

Comment: FYI: Updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

Also be sure to have space on your partition... with the

```
df -h
```

terminal command...