# Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic.postinst line 1010

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apt-get returning 'Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63187/apt-get-returning-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-error)

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 on Dell Inspiron 1564 and Wireless Driver: STA Wireless Driver.

Any idea what's wrong with my package manager?

```
tahir@tahir-Inspiron-1564:/var/www$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for tahir: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic (2.6.35-27.48) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-27-generic                                                                                                 
 *       bcmwl (5.60.48.36+bdcom)...                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic (2.6.35-28.50) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-28-generic                                                                                                 
 *       bcmwl (5.60.48.36+bdcom)...                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic (2.6.35-30.59) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-30-generic                                                                                                 
 *       bcmwl (5.60.48.36+bdcom)...                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/nvidia-common 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
/etc/grub.d/README: 2: All: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 4: 00_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 5: 10_*:: not found
/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 2.6.35.30.38); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--confNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
igure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic
 linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic
 linux-image-2.6.35-30-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Yes looked for the dependency problem but this log does not help to track the exact dependency issue e.g. it would have been good to have the name of the package for which the dependency issue is popping up or it would have been great to know what that dependency issue is. Still figuring out this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From this:

> `/etc/grub.d/README: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`
>
> `run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2`
>
> `Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic.postinst line 1010.`
>
> `dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic (--configure):`
>
> `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2`

It looks like it might be either a grub problem, or a dependency with something in the kernel/os.  To resolve a dependency issue with a version of ubuntu, you can try upgrading the OS with `apt-get` (or boot into a newer OS if you have one on a partition):

> - Update the Package Index
>
>   The APT package index is essentially a database of available packages from the repositories defined in the /etc/apt/sources.list file. To update the local package index with the latest changes made in repositories, type the following:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get update`
>
> - Upgrade Packages: Over time, updated versions of packages currently installed on your computer may become available from the package repositories (for example security updated). To upgrade your system, first update your package index as outlined above, and then type:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`

**All from [Ubuntu apt-get article/documentation](http://linux.about.com/od/ubusrv_doc/a/ubusg11t01.htm)**

> If a package needs to install or remove new dependencies when being upgraded, it will not be upgraded by the upgrade command. For such an upgrade, it is necessary to use the dist-upgrade command.
>
> Also, you may upgrade your entire Ubuntu system from one revision to another with dist-upgrade. For example, to upgrade from Ubuntu version 5.10 to version 6.06 LTS, you would first ensure the version 6.06 LTS repositories replace the existing 5.10 repositories in your computer's /etc/apt/sources.list, then simply issue the apt-get update command as detailed above, and finally, perform the actual upgrade by typing:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> After a fairly considerable amount of time, your computer will be upgraded to the new revision. Typically, some post-upgrade steps would be required as detailed in the upgrade notes for the revision you are upgrading to.

And if there are anyissues along the way, actions of the apt-get command, such as installation and removal of packages, are logged in the `/var/log/dpkg.log` log file.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I had mistakenly set the /etc/grub.d/README to executable. chmod -x /etc/grub.d/README did the magic. :)

Comment: Nice!  Glad u fixed it!